# How to define function only for old versions in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a code that uses the `fromRight` function defined circa GHC 8.2. But I need to downgrade to GHC 8.0.2, which gives an error about `Variable not in scope:` for `fromRight`

I was wondering if it possible and how to add the missing definition

```
fromRight :: b -> Either a b -> b
fromRight _ (Right b) = b
fromRight b _         = b
```

so that it is only used when I use an GHC version than 8.2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write

```
import Prelude hiding (fromRight)
```

which is valid even if `fromRight` does not exist in Prelude. Therefore, if you want to write a module which is compatible with both old and new versions of Prelude, you can simply choose to ignore the new `fromRight` function, and always use the one in your library.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, when you're wondering about a library function, you should use CPP.

```
{-# language CPP #-}

#if !MIN_VERSION_base (4,10,0)
fromRight :: ...
#endif
```

The `MIN_VERSION_...` macros used to be provided by Cabal; now they're provided by GHC. If you want to use them with sufficiently old versions of GHC, you'll need to use Cabal (using either `cabal-install` or `stack`).

---

Before you go to the trouble of doing this, note that there are several packages with names ending in `-compat` that do all the work for you. In this case, you can use the `fromRight` from [`Data.Either.Compat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-compat-0.9.3/docs/Data-Either-Compat.html) in the `base-compat` package. Then you don't have to care whether you're using a new enough `base` library.