# isLeft works but fromLeft is not working in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell .I am trying to run the Data.Either.fromLeft Command in a program.

```
*NumericTypeCast Data.Char Data.List Data.Either> isLeft ( checkIntArgument "ss")
False
*NumericTypeCast Data.Char Data.List Data.Either> fromLeft ( checkIntArgument "ss")

<interactive>:87:1: Not in scope: ‘fromLeft’
*NumericTypeCast Data.Char Data.List Data.Either> fromLeft ( Left "ss")

<interactive>:88:1: Not in scope: ‘fromLeft’
*NumericTypeCast Data.Char Data.List Data.Either>
```

This seems to be odd, while isLeft works fine , fromLeft show error. any thoughts?

Comment: I have imported Data.Either already in my code.

Comment: Which version of `base` are you using? `fromLeft` was added in `4.10.0.01`.

Comment: build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5 is showing in my.cabal file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar question ([How to define function only for old versions in GHC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065477)) about `fromRight`.

And I found that `fromLeft` and `fromRight` are only available in the newer versions of [Data.Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) in GHC 8.2+.  The documentation says they are available:

> Since: 4.10.0.0

--Update--

The answers in the question above show how to make `fromLeft` or `fromRight` work for both older and newer versions of Haskell.

Comment: "The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3" terminal shows above ghc version , is possible to include / install it in this version or do I have to reinstall/upgrade the ghc?

Comment: @mali Yes, please see the update and the answers in the other question. You don't have to reinstall/upgrade.

Comment: thanks! " How to define function only for old versions in GHC? " has a solution for the problem.