# Why do I need Data.Monoid.(<>) only for older GHC?

Tags: haskell, package

In my [Haskell package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma) [builds](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/builds/447136359) prior to GHC 8.4, I need to

```
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
```

to [avoid](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/jobs/447136365#L479)

```
• Variable not in scope:
    (<>)
```

while from GHC 8.4 on, I get no error of I exclude this import.

Why is this? Has `(<>)` been implemented elsewhere? What are the consequences of doing this import for later GHC, where it is unnecessary? Can conditional import this for only for older GHC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why is this?

Because of the [Semigroup Monoid Proposal](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Libraries/Proposals/SemigroupMonoid)

#### Has `(<>)` been implemented elsewhere?

Yes it got defined in `GHC.Base`:

```
[nix-shell:~]$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t (<>)
(<>) :: Semigroup a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :info (<>)
class Semigroup a where
  (<>) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 6 <>
Prelude>
```

#### What are the consequences of doing this import for later GHC, where it is unnecessary?

As of now, there are none, as `Data.Monoid` reexports `(<>)`. If I read the proposal correctly, there are no plans of removing that reexport.

#### Can one do this import conditionally for older GHC only?

Yes, via CPP see here [conditional exclude it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47065610/656912) thanks to orome.

As `Semigroup` became a superclass of `Monoid` in Phase 2b of the proposal and that was done in GHC 8.4, you can check for the version of base being bigger than 4.11.0.0, as you can look up [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package).

Comment: So, though in general one approach here might be to [conditionally exclude it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47065610/656912) for later GHC, in this case that's unnecessary (since all the import is doing is grabbing the same implementation that's already there from `GHC.Base`?

Comment: Yes, you could simply leave the `import Data.Monoid ((<>))` in your code.

Comment: May I suggest you make headings a bit less in-the-face in the future? (`###` instead of `#`.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Arguably, that's an issue for the Markdown renderer; top-level headers *should* be used before lower-level headers.

Comment: @chepner Top-level headers should be used for the main page layout. `<h1>` for the question title and... well, that's basically it; then `<h2>` would introduce the individual answers and each answer is subdivided with `<h3>`s and `<h4>`s. What you could argue is that `#` and `===` should translate straight to `<h3>` rather than `<h1>`, but here we are. For a really long answer it could make sense to use `<h1>` and `<h2>` to divide it into “chapters”, but not for one like this.

Comment: The other option would be to simply use `**...**` to add some formatting, but I wouldn't skip a level of headings just to tweak the appearance.

Comment: Better with the headings now?